# Not the highest - Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Not the highest nor the lowest
With letters on my chest
I often play with others
Some may think I am the best

I usually feel tension
But I think that keeps me straight
I shout out loud and bold
And it's that shout that makes me great

My master and I are best of friends
And our friendship keeps improving
My friends and I unite as one
And that helps keep things moving

Who am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A **cello** or **viola**?

*Not the highest nor the lowest

With letters on my chest*

Thanks to **d'alar'cop** for helping me with these two lines!

> A cello and viola are between the violin (highest) and the double bass (lowest). Both cellos and violas have what look like letter S's printed on their middles.

*I often play with others*

> One of many instruments in an orchestra.

*Some may think I am the best*

> The *first* violin maybe?

*I usually feel tension

But I think that keeps me straight*

> The strings on a stringed instrument are under tension, which keeps them taut and straight.

*I shout out loud and bold

And it's that shout that makes me great*

> The sound emitted by a musical instrument is what it's made for.

*My master and I are best of friends

And our friendship keeps improving*

> A musician and his instrument can have a strong bond.

*My friends and I unite as one

And that helps keep things moving*

> The sound of many instruments playing together in an orchestra can indeed be deeply moving.

Comment: Maybe it's a cello. Violin is higher... Bass is lower. Letters could be those little Ss or the musical notes?

Comment: @d'alar'cop Is a viola between violin and cello? My musical ignorance is showing up strongly here :-p

Comment: Violin is highest.  Double bass is lowest. Cello and viola are in between

Comment: @d'alar'cop OK, thanks for the info! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Seconding the 'S' suggestion for letters on my chest.

Comment: @d'alar'cop or QuestionC: please could you explain the 'S' thing to a musical ignoramibus? :-)

Comment: look at google images for cellos.. they all have some Ss on them